# How to say "children are encouraged to"

Tags: expressions, vocabulaire

How do we say "Children are encouraged to"? my french teacher does not want us to use "encouragé" but a conjugated form of "donner de soutien". How do I do that?

Comment: What's the full sentence, and if it's ambiguous the intended meaning? I can't think of a context where “donner du soutien” could be a translation of “encourage”.

Answer (score 2):

*Encourager* is one possible translation, in the sense of to spur, to push to do something:

> Les enfants sont encouragés à travailler en autonomie.

*Donner du soutien* does not have the exact same meaning: it means to support, to help.

> Les enseignants donnent du soutien aux élèves en difficulté.